# What is the equivalent typescript for my module?

Tags: module, typescript, amd

I am very close to getting what I want but it's not quite there.
I have this:

```
export class RichTextArea {
    text: string;

    constructor(params: any)
    {
        this.text = params.text;
    }
}
```

which is generating this (AMD):

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    var RichTextArea = (function () {
        function RichTextArea(params) {
            self.text= params.text;
        }
        return RichTextArea;
    }());
    exports.RichTextArea = RichTextArea;
});
```

I need it to generate something that looks like this (see change to export):

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    var RichTextArea = (function () {
        function RichTextArea(params) {
            self.text = params.text;
        }
        return RichTextArea;
    }());
    return RichTextArea; //I need this so that it is immediately available
});
```

What do I have to change in my TS to achieve this?
When I import my module, I don't want to have to say mymodule.RichTextArea(params), I want to be able to say mymodule(params)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
class RichTextArea {
    text: string;

    constructor(params: any)
    {
        this.text = params.text;
    }
}

export = RichTextArea;
```

Outputs this code:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    var RichTextArea = (function () {
        function RichTextArea(params) {
            this.text = params.text;
        }
        return RichTextArea;
    }());
    return RichTextArea;
});
```

Comment: I was sooo close, i tried `export RichTextArea`, i didnt assign it! This works perfectly. Thankyou, been struggling with this.